# SPARQL query filtering float values

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am wondering on how to query an annotation that has a float value. I have managed to do this with a string value, but I can not figure out how to do it with a float value. The information I want to retrieve is the value of `curfew:NumberInLine` annotation.  In the case below, it is `50.0`:

```xml
<curfew:NumberInLine rdf:datatype="&xsd;float">50.0</curfew:NumberInLine>
```

I use the following SPARQL query to retrieve strings. That code will give me all of the individuals where there is a `curfew:Label` which contains the string `"Open"`. I want to be able to to the same thing with numbers and float values.

```
SELECT ?x
WHERE
{
  ?x curfew:Label ?label .
  FILTER(CONTAINS(?label, "Open"))
}
```

I tried to replace the `curfew:Label` with `curfew:NumberInLine`, but with no luck. I have a prefix for the `curfew:` as well. I don´t get any errors, just no answers.  How can I modify this query?

Comment: Why did you replace it with `beer:curfew:NumberInLine`?  Shouldn't you replace it with `curfew:NumberInLine`?

Comment: And what do you mean you want to filter this?  Right now you're doing string containment (i.e., substring checking).  You _could_ check whether (the string representation of) a number contains a certain string, but wouldn't it be more useful to check whether, e.g., it's within some range, or something like that?

Comment: Nevermind, a mistake, i edited that.
What I mean is that I know how to retrieve a string from an annotation, but not a float value. So not a number in a string. That´s why I can´t do it.

How would you write a query to find the float value in the NumberInLine-annotation? Thanks

Comment: I've added an answer.  The query pattern is exactly the same: `?x curfew:NumberInLine ?number`.  Of course, you'd probably want to filter based on numeric properties rather than string properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is harder to answer because you haven't shown your data.  However, if we assume you've got some data like this:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://example.org/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:curfew="http://example.org/curfew/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/c">
    <curfew:NumberInLine rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
    >45.0</curfew:NumberInLine>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/a">
    <curfew:NumberInLine rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
    >50.0</curfew:NumberInLine>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/d">
    <curfew:NumberInLine rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
    >47.0</curfew:NumberInLine>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/b">
    <curfew:NumberInLine rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
    >60.0</curfew:NumberInLine>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

then you can filter in the same way (using `contains`) with a query like this:

```
prefix curfew: <http://example.org/curfew/>
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?c ?number where {
  ?c curfew:NumberInLine ?number .
  filter( contains( str(?number), "5" ))
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| c  | number                                           |
=========================================================
| :c | "45.0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> |
| :a | "50.0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

It would be much more common, if you're working with numeric types, though, to filter based on numeric properties.  E.g.,

```
prefix curfew: <http://example.org/curfew/>
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?c ?number where {
  ?c curfew:NumberInLine ?number .
  filter( ?number < 50.0 )
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| c  | number                                           |
=========================================================
| :d | "47.0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> |
| :c | "45.0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I love you! Thank you so much!